# Internet connection problem with web browsers only

Tags: networking, arch-linux

I'm experiencing a strange problem on my ArchLinux box with Gnome Shell 3.18.

Suddenly I cannot surf the internet anymore with any web browser (chrome, FF etc) like the internet connection was down. However the internet connection is up and working and, from the same machine, I can successfully ping remote sites like for example google.com with a good response time (~20ms).

Also, any other device (i.e. my smartphone) connected to the same router/modem can surf the internet without any problem.

It seems something related to "high level" network services since low level stuff (ping, dns resolution etc) works fine.
Restarting NetworkManager service does not help. Switching off/on the wifi, or restarting the X session don't even help. All I can do in this case is to restart the computer.
Any idea?

**EDIT:**

Ok, it happened again. Following to the suggestions int he comments below, here is some output:

```
$ dmesg | grep -i error
[    0.168579] acpi PNP0A08:00: _OSC failed (AE_ERROR); disabling ASPM
[    1.672945] [drm:intel_set_pch_fifo_underrun_reporting [i915]] *ERROR* uncleared pch fifo underrun on pch transcoder A
[    1.672972] [drm:intel_pch_fifo_underrun_irq_handler [i915]] *ERROR* PCH transcoder A FIFO underrun
[ 8222.052784] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: Microcode SW error detected.  Restarting 0x2000000.
[ 8222.053633] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0:                 FH_TSSR_TX_ERROR_REG: 0X00000000
[ 8222.053785] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: Start IWL Error Log Dump:


$ route -n
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.1.1     0.0.0.0         UG    600    0        0 wlp1s0

192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     600    0        0 wlp1s0


$ ifconfig
lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 0  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

wlp1s0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.1.106  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.1.255
        inet6 fe80::caf7:33ff:fe83:a707  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether c8:f7:33:83:a7:07  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 70868  bytes 26910489 (25.6 MiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 64154  bytes 26357208 (25.1 MiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

**EDIT 2:**

```
    ls -al /lib/firmware/ | grep iwlwifi
-rw-r--r--   1 root root  335056 10 dic 16.09 iwlwifi-1000-3.ucode
-rw-r--r--   1 root root  337520 10 dic 16.09 iwlwifi-1000-5.ucode
-rw-r--r--   1 root root  337572 10 dic 16.09 iwlwifi-100-5.ucode
-rw-r--r--   1 root root  689680 10 dic 16.09 iwlwifi-105-6.ucode
-rw-r--r--   1 root root  701228 10 dic 16.09 iwlwifi-135-6.ucode
-rw-r--r--   1 root root  695876 10 dic 16.09 iwlwifi-2000-6.ucode
-rw-r--r--   1 root root  707392 10 dic 16.09 iwlwifi-2030-6.ucode
-rw-r--r--   1 root root  609892 10 dic 16.09 iwlwifi-3160-10.ucode
-rw-r--r--   1 root root  683996 10 dic 16.09 iwlwifi-3160-12.ucode
-rw-r--r--   1 root root  688616 10 dic 16.09 iwlwifi-3160-13.ucode
-rw-r--r--   1 root root  918212 10 dic 16.09 iwlwifi-3160-16.ucode
-rw-r--r--   1 root root  670484 10 dic 16.09 iwlwifi-3160-7.ucode
-rw-r--r--   1 root root  667284 10 dic 16.09 iwlwifi-3160-8.ucode
-rw-r--r--   1 root root  669872 10 dic 16.09 iwlwifi-3160-9.ucode
-rw-r--r--   1 root root  150100 10 dic 16.09 iwlwifi-3945-2.ucode
-rw-r--r--   1 root root  187972 10 dic 16.09 iwlwifi-4965-2.ucode
-rw-r--r--   1 root root  345008 10 dic 16.09 iwlwifi-5000-1.ucode
-rw-r--r--   1 root root  353240 10 dic 16.09 iwlwifi-5000-2.ucode
-rw-r--r--   1 root root  340696 10 dic 16.09 iwlwifi-5000-5.ucode
-rw-r--r--   1 root root  337400 10 dic 16.09 iwlwifi-5150-2.ucode
-rw-r--r--   1 root root  454608 10 dic 16.09 iwlwifi-6000-4.ucode
-rw-r--r--   1 root root  444128 10 dic 16.09 iwlwifi-6000g2a-5.ucode
-rw-r--r--   1 root root  677296 10 dic 16.09 iwlwifi-6000g2a-6.ucode
-rw-r--r--   1 root root  460236 10 dic 16.09 iwlwifi-6000g2b-5.ucode
-rw-r--r--   1 root root  679436 10 dic 16.09 iwlwifi-6000g2b-6.ucode
-rw-r--r--   1 root root  463692 10 dic 16.09 iwlwifi-6050-4.ucode
-rw-r--r--   1 root root  469780 10 dic 16.09 iwlwifi-6050-5.ucode
-rw-r--r--   1 root root  672352 10 dic 16.09 iwlwifi-7260-10.ucode
-rw-r--r--   1 root root  782300 10 dic 16.09 iwlwifi-7260-12.ucode
-rw-r--r--   1 root root  786920 10 dic 16.09 iwlwifi-7260-13.ucode
-rw-r--r--   1 root root 1049284 10 dic 16.09 iwlwifi-7260-16.ucode
-rw-r--r--   1 root root  683236 10 dic 16.09 iwlwifi-7260-7.ucode
-rw-r--r--   1 root root  679780 10 dic 16.09 iwlwifi-7260-8.ucode
-rw-r--r--   1 root root  680508 10 dic 16.09 iwlwifi-7260-9.ucode
-rw-r--r--   1 root root  736844 10 dic 16.09 iwlwifi-7265-10.ucode
-rw-r--r--   1 root root  880604 10 dic 16.09 iwlwifi-7265-12.ucode
-rw-r--r--   1 root root  885224 10 dic 16.09 iwlwifi-7265-13.ucode
-rw-r--r--   1 root root 1180356 10 dic 16.09 iwlwifi-7265-16.ucode
-rw-r--r--   1 root root  690452 10 dic 16.09 iwlwifi-7265-8.ucode
-rw-r--r--   1 root root  697828 10 dic 16.09 iwlwifi-7265-9.ucode
-rw-r--r--   1 root root  740436 10 dic 16.09 iwlwifi-7265D-10.ucode
-rw-r--r--   1 root root 1002800 10 dic 16.09 iwlwifi-7265D-12.ucode
-rw-r--r--   1 root root 1008692 10 dic 16.09 iwlwifi-7265D-13.ucode
-rw-r--r--   1 root root 1384500 10 dic 16.09 iwlwifi-7265D-16.ucode
-rw-r--r--   1 root root 1745176 10 dic 16.09 iwlwifi-8000C-13.ucode
-rw-r--r--   1 root root 2351636 10 dic 16.09 iwlwifi-8000C-16.ucode


$ modinfo iwlwifi | grep -e 7260 -e version
firmware:       iwlwifi-7260-12.ucode
vermagic:       4.3.3-2-ck SMP preempt mod_unload modversions
```

Comment: what is the output of `route -n` and `ifconfig` ? are you behind anything or just a normal router? what is the message displayed by the browsers?

Comment: are you connected by both wired and wifi? if wifi only, what is the output `dmesg | grep -i error` ?

Comment: Thanks for both comments. Next time I'll have the issue I'll run the commands you suggested and post output in my question above!

Comment: If ping and dns work, you should check your proxy settings in the browser. Maybe you are using a proxy of maybe you did something with SELinux

Comment: It would be best to use a packet analyzer, like `tcpdump` or `wireshark`, to see whether http requests leave your pc, and whether suitable replies reach you. I suggest you start either of these two instruments the next time you have this problem.

Comment: It happened again. Plz see my updated question for some output

Comment: Could you post the output of `ls -al /lib/firmware/ | grep iwlwifi` and `modinfo iwlwifi | grep -e 7260 -e version` . it seems to be your card's firmware not the distribution. not necessarily when the problem happens.

Comment: @user3566929 : please check the "Edit 2" section of my question above

Comment: could you try renaming ` iwlwifi-7260-16.ucode`  all the way down to `iwlwifi-7260-10.ucode` to anything else and then unplug and replug so your wifi card reloads a different driver.

Comment: What protocols have you tried? E.g. does FTP work, in a dedicated FTP program (not a web browser)? What is the exact error reported by browsers? Post the output of `curl -I http://example.com`

Comment: @user3566929 I have moved `iwlwifi-7260-16.ucode` all the way down to `iwlwifi-7260-10.ucode` to another folder and restarted the computer. `modinfo iwlwifi | grep -e 7260 -e version` is still outputting `firmware:       iwlwifi-7260-12.ucode`. And I'm having the same issue again...

Comment: try leaving `7260-12.ucode` or `7260-11` in there too, if your issue persists, then file it as a bug to arch's bug team so they could help fixing, as this is a driver issue and unfortunately i don't have time at all cause my father got sick and is dying

Comment: @user3566929 thank'you very much for your hint and I'm very sorry for your father!!